# How to add JavaScript object as a URL's searchParams without looping

Tags: javascript, url

Say I have some data:

```js
let data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

and I want to add that data to an existing URL:

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.mywebsite.com')
```

I'd like to set all of the object's key and value parameters as that URL's `searchParams` without having to `set` or `append` each item directly. I want to set **THE WHOLE THING** as the searchParams.

I just want to pass it in / replace the existing search params somehow. I wish it went like:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(data)
url.searchParams = params
```

or somehow

```js
url.searchParams.set(data) // or .append(data)
```

buuut of course, none of those work.

I'd prefer not to go through `for of` loop with `Object.entries(data)` but I don't see another way, I'm hoping I just didn't find it yet.

Is there an easy way to set MULTIPLE key value pairs / data from an object into a URL's search params to build a new URL?

Desired outcome:

```js
url.toString() // https://www.mywebsite.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the closest thing I've found to an answer, and it works.

Reassign your `URL`'s `.search` to the `String` version of `URLSearchParams`, like so:

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.example.com')
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
const params = new URLSearchParams(data)
url.search = params.toString()  // Convert params to a string and add them to url search
```

The result:

```
console.log(url.toString())  // https://www.example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

It totally works!

---

#### Clean little function (^-^)

```js
const buildURL = (url, params) => {
  url = new URL(url)
  params = new URLSearchParams(params)
  url.search = params.toString()
  return url
}

let url = buildURL('https://example.com', {a: 1, b:2, c:3 })
console.log(url.toString()) // https://example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done. Here's why:

You can create a new `URLSearchParams` object like this: ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams))

```
let data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
const params = new URLSearchParams(data);
console.log(params.get('a')) // => 1
```

However, you cannot assign this object to an existing `URL` object because the `.searchParams` property is read-only ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)). Furthermore, there is no constructor to create a `URL` object from an existing `URLSearchParams` object. There might be a good reason, but there's none that I know of.

Because of this, your best solution is just to use a `for of` loop.